# How do I display a popup while I'm on the primary stage

Tags: java, javafx

I tried using this method to print show a popup with label "THAT'S IT" and I don't want to use the Popup class

```
    public void showStage(Stage Owner){

    HBox hBox = new HBox();
    hBox.getChildren().add(new Label("THAT'S IT"));
    Scene sc = new Scene(hBox);
    Stage popup = new Stage();
    popup.setScene(sc);
    popup.setWidth(400);
    popup.setHeight(100);
    popup.initOwner(owner);
    popup.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    popup.show();
    }
```

and then I call the `showStage()` method from the start method

```
     public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Label lb = new Label();

    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(e->{
         lb.setText("hello everyone");showStage(primaryStage);
    });
```

But the output of the code :

[image]

Comment: If I fix the typo (`Stage Owner` -> `Stage owner`), I cannot reproduce this issue. Voting for close as off topic since the information in the answer is insufficient to reproduce or it's a simple typo.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a dialog? 
You can use it in your main controller class without creating an other stage for instance like this:

```
Dialog dialogQtPrescription = new Dialog();   
dialogQtPrescription.setTitle("yourTitle");
dialogQtPrescription.setHeaderText("yourHeadertext");
dialogQtPrescription.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
dialogQtPrescription.initOwner(mainStage);
dialogQtPrescription.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);

GridPane gridDialogPrescription = new GridPane();
gridDialogPrescription.setHgap(10);
gridDialogPrescription.setVgap(10);
gridDialogPrescription.add(new Label(bundle.getString("quantityPrescription.title")), 0, 0);
TextField txtQtPrescr = new TextField();
ButtonType buttonTypeNo = new ButtonType("no");
ButtonType buttonTypeYes = new ButtonType("yes");
ButtonType buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
dialogQtPrescription.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(buttonTypeNo,buttonTypeYes, buttonTypeCancel);

txtQtPrescr.setPrefWidth(100);

gridDialogPrescription.add(txtQtPrescr, 1, 0);
dialogQtPrescription.getDialogPane().setContent(gridDialogPrescription);

Optional<ButtonType> result = dialogQtPrescription.showAndWait();
```

this is just a stack of code from a project but i hope it make you to understand my idea.

here's better explained: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in order to make a Popup on any Screen in JavaFX

```
public void popup() {
        final Stage dialog = new Stage();
        dialog.setTitle("Confirmation");
        Button yes = new Button("Yes");
        Button no = new Button("No");

        Label displayLabel = new Label("What do you want to do ?");
        displayLabel.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 14));

        dialog.initModality(Modality.NONE);
        dialog.initOwner((Stage) tableview.getScene().getWindow());

        HBox dialogHbox = new HBox(20);
        dialogHbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        VBox dialogVbox1 = new VBox(20);
        dialogVbox1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        VBox dialogVbox2 = new VBox(20);
        dialogVbox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        dialogHbox.getChildren().add(displayLabel);
        dialogVbox1.getChildren().add(yes);
        dialogVbox2.getChildren().add(no);

        yes.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                        // inside here you can use the minimize or close the previous stage//
                        dialog.close();
                    }
                });
        no.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                        dialog.close();
                    }
                });

        dialogHbox.getChildren().addAll(dialogVbox1, dialogVbox2);
        Scene dialogScene = new Scene(dialogHbox, 500, 40);
        dialogScene.getStylesheets().add("//style sheet of your choice");
        dialog.setScene(dialogScene);
        dialog.show();
    }
```